# Mallet, probabilities of labels

Tags: probability, mallet, crf

I'm trying to use the Mallet Simple Tagger (http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/sequences.php) for detecting specific kinds of words in texts (specifically, prominent words). I'm running it with following standard commands:

for training

```
java -cp "C:\mallet\class;C:\mallet\lib\mallet-deps.jar" cc.mallet.fst.SimpleTagger --train true --model-file "ab.crf" "data/train.txt" --threads 3
```

for testing

```
java -cp "C:\mallet\class;C:\mallet\lib\mallet-deps.jar" cc.mallet.fst.SimpleTagger --model-file "ab.crf" "data\test.txt" >> "result.txt"
```

After testing I get a list of labels as a result (0 or 1 for each word in the training set). I would like to know, is it somehow possible to output a probability of a label (not the label itself)?

Thank you